# Verify SQL parameter value is correct type c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Hi I am looking for a way to verify that the string that I am adding to a `SqlCommand` as parameter is correct.
Here is my code :

```
string wrongType = "This is not a date";
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = wrongType;
```

Is there a way to check if `wrongType` can be converted to a `SqlDbType.DateTime` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
string wrongType = "This is not a date";
DateTime rightTyped;

if(DateTime.TryParse(wrongType, out rightTyped)) 
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = rightTyped;
}
```

Comment: This code is odd in that it fails to add the parameter in the failure case (but still attempts to work normally). It also implicitly advocates keeping UI code (parsing, etc) too close to DB code. By the time your code is talking about DB concerns, it shouldn't have any raw inputs - they should already be parsed, IMO.

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand your concerns, but you know that the question is very generic and, thus, the answer will be generic. My answer isn't describing your concern: it's an oversimplification like the question itself, isn't it? :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I was going to edit to add an `else` in order to throw a possible exception like `FormatException` but it defeats the point of using `TryParse`....

Answer (score 1):

If you get user input, you must validate input in place.

Try this:

```
string wrongType = "This is not a date";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParse(wrongType, out date))
{
    // staff when string converted
}
```

Comment: Yes it comes from a user, so I suppose this is the easiest way, sad that add parameter does not raise an exception if the value cannot be parsed into the SqlDbType

Comment: Be aware, that this is just idea of exception-free parsing. You must pass parameter of correct type to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first line:

```
string wrongType = "This is not a date";
```

If it has to be a date, and if your TSQL is working against a date, then... ***use a date***:

```
DateTime rightType = ...
```

Now it is never wrong. Basically, stop relying on strings. The rest of the code remains similar:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = rightType;
```

Note that you can use `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse` to get from string input to a DateTime.

Comment: Ok, and what if input comes from user? (I guess this is OP's case).

Comment: @Matias then you use parse/tryparse. You certainly don't send it to the database as a string. This is also why you should keep DB code and UI code separate.

Comment: Absolutely, you won't be sending strings.